# english to arabic within url messing up arabic

Tags: php, javascript, browser, encoding

I am trying to pass through arabic via the url then grabbing it as a session work fine in english.

say i have the follwoing

```
www.example.com?subject=الاختبار
```

this then goes of to a jquery ajax post then it comes back to the browser like below????

```
 Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø®ØªØ¨Ø§Ø±

      var params = { 
            sessionid: "<?php if(isset($_GET['sessionid'])){echo $_GET['sessionid'];}else{ echo ""; } ?>",
            subject: <?php if(isset($_GET['subject'])){echo  "'".$_GET['subject']."'";}else{ echo ''; } ?>,
                          };


             $.post("ajax_login.php", params,function(data){

 if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
          {
                 document.location='secure.php';
          }
          else 
          {
                 alert("Woops their seems to be a problem please check back later.");
          }

        }
```

then ajax_login.php is

```
   <?php session_start();

echo "yes";
//now set the session from here if needed

$user = array();  
$user['sessionid'] = $_POST['sessionid'];
$user['subject'] = $_POST['subject'];

$_SESSION['user'] = $user;

if($_SESSION['user']){

    //print_r($_SESSION);

}else{
    echo "there is an error";
    exit();
}
```

then i am just doing a print_r($_SESSION['user']) in secure.php

Comment: Show us your code that's doing this, including a hint as to the *language* you're using.

Comment: hi i have added the code above and the language is arabic???

Comment: No, the language is *PHP* and *Javascript*, apparently.

Comment: yes sorry php and jquery

Comment: i think i have located the issues if you go here http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_charsets and then typ in the following اختبار اختبار you get ?????? looking for a multi language charset

Comment: sorted  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >

Answer (score 0):

First: Make sure that you are not making extra encoding before grabbing the `$_GET['subject']`

Second : In your favorite text editor ex. `Notepad++` make sure that the Encoding is

`Encode UTF-8 without BOM`

also try to be sure that the page charset is utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is PHP that is not interpreting the URL properly -- try setting/ensuring that your default character-set in PHP is UTF-8 so that it handles Arabic characters properly.

change/add this in your php.ini file

`default_charset = "utf-8"`